# How do I change the x labels on a boxchart plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, boxplot

I have a script for a boxchart plot, but I cannot find anywhere how to change the labels of the x axis. I want the 1, 2 and 3 replaced by h_d^e, h_c^e and h_*^e (in Latex notation, ofcourse). Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```
x=rand(3,3);
figure
hbx = boxchart(x);
xMdn = median(x);
boxw = hbx.BoxWidth;
xd = 1:numel(hbx.XData);
hold on
plot(0.5*boxw*[-1;1]+xd, [1;1]*xMdn, '-r','LineWidth',1.5)
hold off
box on
grid on
set(gca,'FontSize',14) 
set(gcf, 'color', 'white')
hbx.MarkerStyle = '+';
hbx.MarkerColor = 'r';
set(gca,'Yscale','log')
```

Comment: Does this help any: [Question about labels under each boxplot](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/30338-question-about-labels-under-each-boxplot)

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome Thank you, but not really, there is a different approach for a "boxchart" than a "boxplot" apparently, as boxplot does not recognize labels: Unrecognized property labels for class BoxChart.

Comment: Any issue using the function for renaming axis labels - `xticklabels`?